# How to prevent a tkinter frame from resizing in a set of frames

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

For a simulation application, I'm designing an UI with Tkinter module in python. I'm currently trying to add constraints to frames and window size to keep a good interface no matter the size of the window.

In a part of my UI, I have something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

topframe=       Frame(master=root,bg='red')
midframe=       Frame(master=root,bg='blue')
bottomframe=    Frame(master=root,bg='yellow')

toplabel=       Label(master=topframe,bg='red',text='Must be non resizable unless window cannot fit it \n (Contains buttons)',height=10)
midlabel=       Label(master=midframe,bg='blue',text='Must be resizable \n (Contains a graph)',height=10)
bottomlabel=    Label(master=bottomframe,bg='yellow',text='Must be non resizable unless window cannot fit it \n (Contains simulation results)',height=10)

toplabel.pack(fill=X,expand=TRUE)
midlabel.pack(fill=X,expand=TRUE)
bottomlabel.pack(fill=X,expand=TRUE)

topframe.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=FALSE)
midframe.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=TRUE)
bottomframe.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=FALSE)

root.mainloop()
```

So I get and window like this:

[The window I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVWOi.png)

But my problem is, as I resize the window to get smaller, the yellow parts shrinks until it disappears but I would like to keep to size fixed and the blue part to shrinks (frame in the middle). Does anyone have an idea to do this?

I already tried grid_propagate(False) and I already watched related questions but either it has no effects either it does not fit my example. Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grid()` instead of `pack()` this can be accomplished as demonstrated below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

topframe = Frame(root, bg='red')
midframe = Frame(root, bg='blue')
bottomframe = Frame(root, bg='yellow')

root.rowconfigure([0,2], minsize=90)    # Set min size for top and bottom
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)          # Row 1 should adjust to window size
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)       # Column 0 should adjust to window size
topframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')   # sticky='nsew' => let frame 
midframe.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')   # fill available space
bottomframe.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

toplabel = Label(topframe, bg='red', text='Must be non resizable unless window cannot fit it \n (Contains buttons)',height=10)
midlabel = Label(midframe, bg='blue', text='Must be resizable \n (Contains a graph)',height=10)
bottomlabel = Label(bottomframe, bg='yellow', text='Must be non resizable unless window cannot fit it \n (Contains simulation results)',height=10)

toplabel.pack(fill=X,expand=TRUE)
midlabel.pack(fill=X,expand=TRUE)
bottomlabel.pack(fill=X,expand=TRUE)

root.mainloop()
```

You will probably want to set a window minimum size as well.

Comment: Yes I already applied it in my real application but then the middle frame (blue frame) cannot shrink to lower size than it's initial size. So it doesn't solve my problem